# Extract non null elements from a list

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
    x = list(a = 1:4, b = 3:10, c = NULL)
    x
    #$a
    #[1] 1 2 3 4
    #
    #$b
    #[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
    #
    #$c
    #NULL
```

and I want to extract all elements that are not null. How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), x)
```

Answer (score 13):

What about:

```
x[!unlist(lapply(x, is.null))]
```

---

Here is a brief description of what is going on.

1. `lapply` tells us which elements are `NULL`

   ```
   R> lapply(x, is.null)
   $a
   [1] FALSE

   $b
   [1] FALSE

   $c
   [1] TRUE
   ```
2. Next we convect the list into a vector:

   ```
   R> unlist(lapply(x, is.null)) 
   a     b     c 
   FALSE FALSE  TRUE
   ```
3. Then we switch `TRUE` to `FALSE`:

   ```
   R> !unlist(lapply(x, is.null))
       a     b     c 
   TRUE  TRUE FALSE
   ```
4. Finally, we select the elements using the usual notation:

   ```
   x[!unlist(lapply(x, is.null))]
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't `x[!sapply(x, is.null)]` be faster?

Answer (score 13):

```
x[!sapply(x,is.null)]
```

This generalizes to any logical statement about the list, just sub in the logic for "is.null".

Answer (score 1):

Simpler and likely quicker than the above, the following works for lists of any non-recursive (in the sense of `is.recursive`) values:

```r
example_1_LST <- list(NULL, a=1.0, b=Matrix::Matrix(), c=NULL, d=4L)
example_2_LST <- as.list(unlist(example_1_LST, recursive=FALSE))
```

`str(example_2_LST)` prints:

```
List of 3
 $ a: num 1
 $ b:Formal class 'lsyMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. ..@ x       : logi NA
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1 1
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ d: int 4
```

Comment: You don't need to refer to functions in base and utils with `base::` and `utils::`.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `%in%`.

```r
x[!x %in% list(NULL)]
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4
#
#$b
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or `is.null` in `vapply`.

```r
x[!vapply(x, is.null, FALSE)]
```

Or to use `lengths`, but this will **fail** in case the list contains e.g. `numeric(0)`.

```r
x[lengths(x) > 0]
```

---

Benchmark

```r
x = list(a = 1:4, b = 3:10, c = NULL)
bench::mark(
sapply = x[!sapply(x,is.null)],
Filter = Filter(Negate(is.null), x),
"in" = x[!x %in% list(NULL)],
lapply = x[!unlist(lapply(x, is.null))],
vapply = x[!vapply(x, is.null, FALSE)],
lengths = x[lengths(x) > 0] )
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 sapply     19.85µs 22.73µs    40853.        0B    12.3   9997     3    244.7ms
#2 Filter     11.84µs 13.73µs    70067.        0B    14.0   9998     2    142.7ms
#3 in          9.87µs 11.45µs    81415.        0B     8.14  9999     1    122.8ms
#4 lapply       6.4µs  7.49µs   126673.        0B    12.7   9999     1     78.9ms
#5 vapply      4.64µs  5.51µs   177842.        0B    17.8   9999     1     56.2ms
#6 lengths     2.12µs  2.32µs   414271.        0B     0    10000     0     24.1ms
```

Comment: Actually for package development vapply() should probably be used as you suggest here.
I would have actually written it a little bit differently. See below:
`x[!vapply(x, is.null, logical(length = 1L))]`
No idea how much different it is from using `FALSE` or if it has an impact on the benchmark. Any idea?

Comment: `logical(length = 1L)` gives `FALSE`. In benchmark I would not expect a difference.