# Get the indices of the non-null items of a 2-dimension list

Tags: r, list

I've been looking for a simple (i.e. base R) function (or combination thereof) to extract the indices of the non-null items of a 2-dimension list but didn't find anything.

So I've built the following function but I have the strong feeling I am thereby reinventing the wheel:

```
MyList <- vector("list", length = 10)
MyList[[2]] <- 785
MyList[[9]] <- list(85, 4, 15, 10)

counter <- 0
non_null_indices <- unlist(lapply(X = MyList, FUN = function(List.Item){
    counter <<- counter + 1
    if(!is.null(List.Item)) return(counter)
}))
non_null_indices
```

Do you know an alternative way, more in the base R spirit, to do this?

Comment: you can use `which(lengths(MyList) > 0)`

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know this function `lengths` - only `length`.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16896376/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` with `which`.

```
which(!MyList %in% list(NULL))
#[1] 2 9
```

or

```
which(!sapply(MyList, is.null))
```

or

```
which(!vapply(MyList, is.null, FALSE))
```

Alternatively you can use `lengths` like shown in a comment from @Gerald T (Thanks!), but this will **fail** in case the list contains e.g. `numeric(0)`.

```
which(lengths(MyList) > 0)
#[1] 2 9
```